# Issue with remote connection to SSAS Tabular via non-Domain laptop

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssas, tabular, ssas-tabular

Just a quick bit of background to help with this.  I am a consultant working with a client on some reporting development.  I have a VPN to their site and can successfully connect to their SQL servers to run queries in SSMS and Excel.  I have also built PowerPivot workbooks that connect to these servers.  I use SQL server authentication to connect as Windows authentication would not work, given that I am not an employee and not logged on to a domain account.

We installed SSAS Tabular (successfully) in order to upload one of the power pivot data models onto a server environment.  The service is running on the server.  We can see the tabular object on SSMS and can see the services listed on SSCM.

The issue arises when I use my laptop to try to connect to the Tabular object but my machine can't see it or connect to it on SSMS, Excel, Visual Studio.  Is this because Analysis Services DOES NOT have the equivalent of SQL server authentication?  As a data model developer, must I be logged into a domain machine as a domain user with admin rights to the tabular object?  Is there a way I can connect from my home & personal laptop?

I would be very grateful for any help & advice you can offer

Many Thanks in advance

Stuart

SSAS Tabular on SQL Server 2016; My Laptop: Windows 10 pro; SSMS 17.1 installed on server & my laptop; visual studio 2017 + AS/RS addons installed on my laptop; Let me know if you need more environment info

Comment: If you are out of domain ,Sometimes VPN Connection is not stable.If that is the case.Try to connect to VPN or internet using some other Faster Internet just to test(I faced this issue personally).

Answer (score 1):

you can try running ssms on your laptop with following command from command prompt.

runas /netonly /user:domain\username "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\ssms.exe"

(ssms.exe path may vary as per the installation directory, you need to replace with the one on your laptop)

This should enable you to connect to ssas from non-domain machine, provided you have domain user credentials and vpn connectivity on.